# Create a bidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I confess that I am a beginner. My goal is to be able to summarize in a two-dimensional table the amount per month (in column) for each class (in line). After doing a lot of research, I arrived at this stage in my project.

My problem is , I get the result with months repeating in columns like here.

[image: My result]

Here is my code.
This is my sql code :

```
"SELECT classe, mois, sum_ec FROM journal"
```

This is my php code :

```
<?php

$tableau = array();
$tblClasse = array();
$rt = mysqli_query($db, $req_sit);//execute la requete
while ($row = $rt->fetch_assoc()){ //forme le tableau
    $tableau[$row['classe']][$row['mois']] = $row['sum_ec'];

    if (!in_array($row['classe'],$tblClasse)) { 
        $tblClasse[] = $row['mois']; 
    }
}

echo '<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>';

foreach ($tblClasse as $classe) {
    echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($classe) . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($tableau as $mois=>$value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $new_line = TRUE;
    foreach ($tblClasse as $classe) {
        if ($new_line) {
            echo '<td>' . $mois . '</td>';
            $new_line = FALSE;
        }

        $display = isset($value[$classe]) ?   $value[$classe] : "&nbsp;";
        echo '<td>' . $display . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Can someone tell me what mistake I made?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
if (!in_array($row['classe'],$tblClasse)) { 
    $tblClasse[] = $row['mois']; 
}
```

You are adding months (Fev, Mar) to the array and trying to check if it contains classes (PS, MS etc.) which is impossible, and this condition always returns true, so Feb is added to the $tblClasse array at each iteration. You must either check months or classes and add months or classes to the array respectively. And if you want the array to contain unique values (for example, months), use keys instead of values:

```
if (!array_key_exists ($row['mois'],$tblClasse)) { 
    $tblClasse[$row['mois']] = 1; 
}
```

Where 1 can be replaced with any other value.

In the further part of your code use the keys, not values of $tblClasse array to form the table heading.

```
foreach (array_keys ($tblClasse) as $mois) {
    echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($mois) . '</th>';
}
```

Comment: Hey Abdulla, I am convinced by your explanation. I try to modify my code and I will come back here to give a feedback. thank you in advance for this quick response

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! It worked. I just had to change the line for the values ​​to "array_keys"

```
foreach (array_keys($tblClasse) as $classe) {
        if ($new_line) {
        echo '<td>' . $mois . '</td>';
        $new_line = FALSE;
        }
```

as well and boom! It's perfect. Thank you very much my dear. You have given me a lot of happiness.